# Storing class instances in a file

Tags: c++, class, instances

I'm attempting to make an RPG using c++, for now just a text RPG. I'm wanting to create lots of instances of the class "monster". Lets say I need to make 100 monsters(goblins, ogres, dragon, etc.), how should I store these? Should I have a separate file dedicated to storing class instances and if so, how? I would like to have them all in a single file so it doesn't take up space elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the class in a `binary` file and use `write` and `read`.

Maybe this is what you want to do, here is a simple example.
Let's say we have this class:

```
class Goblin {
public:
    int health;
    int damage;
};
```

And a file to *write* to:

```
fstream file("record.bin", ios::trunc | ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
```

Now we can create a `Goblin` object:

```
Goblin my_goblin;
my_goblin.health = 100;
my_goblin.damage = 50;
```

And then we can write the data into the binary file:

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&my_goblin.health), sizeof(my_goblin.health));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&my_goblin.damage), sizeof(my_goblin.damage));
```

After running that, the binary file will contain data about your `Goblin` class.

---

Now, for reading the data you don't want the `ios::trunc` flag there:

```
fstream file("record.bin", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
```

We create a `Goblin` object again:

```
Goblin goblin;
```

And then we can read data into our class:

```
if (!file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&goblin.health), sizeof(goblin.health))) {
    // handle error
}
if (!file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&goblin.damage), sizeof(goblin.damage))) {
    // handle error
}
```

Now print to see if it's working:

```
// Output result if all went well
cout << "Goblin health = " << goblin.health << '\n';
cout << "Goblin damage = " << goblin.damage << '\n';
```

Output:

```
Goblin health = 100
Goblin damage = 50
```

This is really not necessary!

For making a text based game, you don't need the approach above. Just write your classes and keep them in header files. Separate declaration from implementation.

Ex: `Goblin.h` , `Goblin.cpp`, `Dragon.h` , `Dragon.cpp` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example, I probably will just store them in header files though like you suggested, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store instances of objects in files, this is called serialization, and there are a number of ways to accomplish it, I suggest more research in that direction.

I believe you will not have to do this for your program, as there will likely be enough space to store all of your monsters, and then some.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, I'll do some research in serialization and see what its all about.